# Arrays on a class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I want to insert variables in a integer array on this class. [This is the website](http://www.codemiles.com/java-examples/shortest-job-first-preemptive-algorithm-t10785.html).

I would like to know if is possible because every time I get an error and I try to set and a get some variables but nothing works

This is the part that I want to insert into an int array and then print it:

```
if(processNow.getBurstTime()==1)
{
    System.out.println(processNow.getName()+" executed from: "+startProcessing+"--> "+Time  );

    // here i want to have my array for example like 
    //int[] startTime2 = new int[];
    //startTime2[]=startProcessing;

    startProcessing=Time;
    inQueue.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This explanation is only to solve the problem with the array. I can not ensure that the rest of your code is working.

An array is not dynamic like a list, at initialization you must provide a size for the array.

```
int[] startTime2 = new int[x];
```

x = size of the array

If you want an array with 5 "places" where you can store your information, x would be five.

Same thing, if you want to fill your array you have to say, which position you want to fill e.g.

```
startTime2[0]=startProcessing;
```

NOTE: arrays are 0 based, for an array with the size of [5] you have the indices 0-4 everything else would cause an index out of bounds exception.